# Excel: Link to "Place in This Document" Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am experiencing an issue with Microsoft Excel Hyperlinks.
Currently I have chosen Insert Hyperlink > Place in This Document > "Page Name" under the Cell Reference menu (Cell reference selected is A1).
For some reason this opens up the same Excel file in my browser rather than swap to the correct sheet in the already open file using the native Excel client.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't do this if you're selecting a sheet through the hyperlink ui, so try some of these steps to troubleshoot:

- Does it continue to act like this in a new workbook?
- Does it do this on another PC?
- If you hover over the hyperlink created this way, does it look like this?

  `file:///C:\folder\names\filename.xlsx - Sheet2!A1` (It should not have `http://` at the beginning.)
- Try to manually create an internal link by using the hyperlink formula:

  `=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A1","My link to sheet 2")`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply! :) I do not have this problem when creating a new workbook or using other templates. This issue is across all PCs so it must be an issue with only this workbook or the options set for the workbook, however I cannot find anything that relates to the problem. Even manually copying your previous formula (  =HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A1","My link to sheet 2")  ) automatically opens in a browser window rather than switches to the other sheet.

Comment: That's a weird one - are there any macros in the doc, or add-ins in play? Can you copy the data to a new workbook and use links there? Is "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange" enabled?